# Read large executable file c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio

There is a file on my HD that is around 1 GB in size. I would like to read this file into a byte array. The issue is that Visual Studio is throwing a 'System.OutOfMemoryException'. Is there some way to handle a file this large within a byte array? I need it on a byte array because I would like to append data to specific parts of the file and then write the appended data back onto my HD.

Thank you,
Evan

Comment: If you modify an executable file, any virus protection will sound an alarm.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't read the whole file into Byte array at once. Read the file in chunks

```
InputStream is = new FileInputStream(some file);
// Create the byte array to hold the data
byte[] bytes = new byte[Somelength];

// Read in the bytes
int offset = 0;
int numRead = 0;
while (offset < bytes.length && (numRead=is.read(bytes, offset, bytes.length-offset)) >= 0) 
{
    offset += numRead;

    //do whatever you want do do with byes
}

// Ensure all the bytes have been read in
if (offset < bytes.length) 
{
   throw new IOException("Could not completely read file "+file.getName());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need to insert data into the middle of the file, I suggest you create a *new* file. Alternate between copying data from the original file and inserting the new data. There's no need to have much of it in memory at a time.

Copying a particular "chunk" should be as simple as:

```
public static void CopyChunk(Stream input, Stream output, int size)
{
    byte[] buffer = new byte[16 * 1024];
    while (size > 0)
    {
        int bytesRead = input.Read(buffer, 0, Math.Min(size, bufer.Length));
        if (bytesRead == 0)
        {
            // Or just return if you want - it depends on how you want to handle
            // the situation.
            throw new IOException("Not enough input data");
        }
        output.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
        size -= bytesRead;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you run .NET4 you [MemoryMappedFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/nb-no/library/system.io.memorymappedfiles.memorymappedfile.aspx) class can be useful in these kind of situations.

It's beneficial if you run on 64bit CPU otherwise you have to have a sliding view of the data (64bit address space can easily hold 1GB)

Answer (score 0):

Read a part, inspect it, add extra bytes when needed, write to new file. Repeat until all is processed.